# How can I select the texts on this page?

Tags: html, copy-paste

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. But how would one go about selecting text on this page (I'm trying to copy and paste to a dictionary online).

http://novel.naver.com/best/detail.nhn?novelId=189212&volumeNo=1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try disabling JavaScript?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tried disabling javascript using web developer tools, text is still not highlight-able.

Comment: did you try, `right-click->View Source`? With javascript disabled.

Comment: Disabling the javascript and view page source works to some extent, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuld find the node you need (paragraph with text) in the DOM tree and copy it. Use DOM inspector (ctrl+shift+K in Mozzila or `ctrl+shift+I in Chrome -> choose DOM inspector).

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome's web developer tools and Javascript turned off, simply `right-click->Inspect element` now in the `Elements` tab of the Inspector select the `<head></head>` tag and `right-click->Delete Node`, now the text will be highlight-able.